# focus not working for div in IE

Tags: javascript

```
this._createPickerElement = function() {

        this.elem = document.createElement('div');
        this.elem.setAttribute("id", "myDiv");
        this.elem.classList.add('vanilla-color-picker');
        var _this = this;

        if (className) {
            this.elem.classList.add(className);
        }

        var currentlyChosenColorIndex = colors.indexOf(this.targetElem.dataset.vanillaPickerColor);

        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            this.elem.innerHTML += singleColorTpl(colors[i], i + 1,
                    i == currentlyChosenColorIndex, noColor);
        }
        this.targetElem.parentNode.appendChild(this.elem);
        this.elem.setAttribute('tabindex', 1);

        var toFocus = currentlyChosenColorIndex > -1 ? currentlyChosenColorIndex : 0;

        this.elem.children[toFocus].focus();
        this.elem.children[toFocus].addEventListener('blur', this_._onFocusLost);
```

focus not working in IE11
when i click this.elem.children[toFocus] not fire click event, only blur fire

```
    this.elem.children[toFocus].focus()
```

is now working............
any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>try to modify like that :</del>

```
 /**
 * removed by edit
 * this.elem.children[toFocus].select();//<-- add this line only for HTMLInuputElement
 **/ 
this.elem.children[toFocus].focus();
```

---

*Edit* :

**Quickly**
You have to set which elements can receive a FocusEvent, by adding an tabindex on elements.

```
if( ! this.elem.children[toFocus].tabindex )
    this.elem.children[toFocus].tabindex = -1; // -1 to let the browser determining the order
```

**Long** :

## 7.4.1 Sequential focus navigation and the tabindex attribute

The tabindex content attribute allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus navigation. The name "tab index" comes from the common use of the "tab" key to navigate through the focusable elements. The term "tabbing" refers to moving forward through the focusable elements that can be reached using sequential focus navigation.

The tabindex attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid integer.

Each element can have a tabindex focus flag set, as defined below. This flag is a factor that contributes towards determining whether an element is focusable, as described in the next section.

You can read more here :

[w3.org focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.elem.children[toFocus].select is not a function

Comment: Sorry, i use to do that, but i've just verified and this is used *only* on HTMLInputElement. But i updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks!! elements is div, so i changed div to button